# Export mySQL database rows as text files?

Tags: mysql, file, text, export

How would I export each row of a result set to it's own text file in MySql?

Just wondering if it's possible to export each row (from a specific column) to multiple text files, so that each row is output to an individual .txt file?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But you'd need to write some code to do it. Execute the query, fetch each row, and for each row, open a filehandle, write whatever to the filehandle, and close the filehandle.

If you want to do this from within MySQL, you could make use of MySQL extensions to SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
```

-or-

```
SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE
```

But you would need to execute a separate statement for each "text file" you want to produce, and you'd want to LIMIT the query to returning a single row.

As a *very* inefficient example of one way to do this, for the number of rows in the table, loop through:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,1 INTO OUTFILE 'row_1.txt' ;
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 1,1 INTO OUTFILE 'row_2.txt' ;
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 2,1 INTO OUTFILE 'row_3.txt' ;
```

That's very inefficient for large sets. And, there's potential for someone to insert or delete rows while this is running, and you have potential for "missing" a row and/or getting a "duplicate".

For large sets, you'd want more efficient queries. With a list of id values, you could loop through those and do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 5 LIMIT 1 INTO OUTFILE 'id_5.txt' ;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 7 LIMIT 1 INTO OUTFILE 'id_7.txt' ;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 11 LIMIT 1 INTO OUTFILE 'id_11.txt' ;
```

With a separate program, you could run just one query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id;
```

And then fetch through the rows, and write each row to a separate file.